# Change MenuItem header and icon based on viewmodel property binding

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, menuitem, datatrigger

I cannot figure out how to do this, and one would think it would be pretty simple.

I have a `MenuItem` that's part of a `ContextMenu`.  I have a `binding` to a boolean property on a viewmodel.  Depending on the state of this property, I want the `MenuItem`'s header text and icon to change.

I could certainly use an `IValueConverter` for this, but I'm sure that there is a more elegant solution using a `DataTemplate` and triggers.  I just can't figure out the proper markup.

The code I worked up (snipped below) has two problems: one the `HeaderTemplate` doesn't appear to contain the icon, so what would be the `MenuItems`'s text contains the icon as well (normally the icon appears on in left hand section - see image and compare with the Copy and Clear menuitems).  Additionally, clicking the `MenuItem` doesn't trigger the `DataTemplate` changes (note the command works, the viewmodel binding does in fact toggle the true/false state).

```
   <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Command="{Binding Source={x:Static cmd:Commands.PauseCommand}}"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                <MenuItem.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image x:Name="img" Source="../Icons/pause.png"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="txt" Text="Pause"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPaused}" Value="True" >
                                <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="../Icons/play.png" TargetName="img"/>
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="Play" TargetName="txt"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </MenuItem.HeaderTemplate>
            </MenuItem>
```

[image: MenuItem]

Comment: If you're going to down-vote, please give a reason.

Comment: Im not the downvoter, but some snippets might help

Comment: I guess I'm looking for a general example of a datatemplate that can perform the requested function (i.e. a menuitem template that changes icon and header based on model property).

Comment: That wont happen, since noone knows your code and there is nothing like a general example. It depends on your XAML and ViewModel

Comment: Added current code plus image.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean like this? Dont make things harder than they are ;)

```
<ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Command="{Binding Source={x:Static cmd:Commands.PauseCommand}}"
                  CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                            <MenuItem.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                                    <Setter Property="Icon" Value="../Icons/play.png>"></Setter>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPaused, Mode=OneWay}" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Icon" Value="../Icons/pause.png"></Setter>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </MenuItem.Style>
                        </MenuItem>
                    </ContextMenu>
```

Comment: Trust me, I don't want to make things harder. :(   Thank you, works perfect.